# Get entries which have content like '%findme%'

Tags: plugin-development, entries, database

I am creating a more robust find and replace plugin which shows what is being replaced and where. I need to query for all entries(or content records?) where content is like '%findme%'.

Should I query for entries or should I query for content records for this find and replace?

I saw that there is an `EntryRecord`, so I can give it CDBCriteria object to find but there is no `ContentRecord` so how do I get the content with the string in it?

This is all I have so far.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->limit = $model->limit;
$relaventContent = ContentService::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you what you prefer to use. Usually people use the `ElementCriteriaModel`. You could achieve your goal with the record itself too but it requires more code.

The `ElementCriteriaModel` provides more ready-to-use options and returns populated entries, `Records` provide only records, so no populated entries with all relations and such

I'm not sure what that `$model->limit` is supposed to do, maybe this is a setting in your globals, but you would normally search for entries that contains something (you can find the rules [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching)) with this code

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->search = 'yourKeyWord';
$relaventContent = $criteria->find();
```

If you just want to have all entries you would do

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->limit = null;
$relaventContent = $criteria->find();
```